# Images don't resize

Tags: c1-cms

I've upgraded to C1 ver 4.1.5058.34326. Since this upgrade, resizing image doesn't work - jpeg images are in full size. I've tried both mw parameter (depreciated in doc, but console uses it as max width) and w&fit parameters. But no difference. Image is inserted in a standard way with console insert dialog.

In source:

```
/media(da435003-5ea6-4f9d-a87f-c3e915c002b5)?mw=80
```

...renders as
    /media/da435003-5ea6-4f9d-a87f-c3e915c002b5/522483685/plakaty/20140116avoid.jpg?mw=80

Full URL is here:
http://new.skrytypuvabbyrokracie.cz/media/da435003-5ea6-4f9d-a87f-c3e915c002b5/522483685/plakaty/20140116avoid.jpg?mw=80

**EDIT:** But some jpegs works, for example http://new.skrytypuvabbyrokracie.cz/media/e8c2dd55-c0b3-49a1-ad91-ef96fe51491f/486720786/cd-images/ourednikovyreferaty_cd.jpg?mw=60

Are the jpegs different?

Comment: The reason for it wokring on some images are that in 4.1 the beginning of the images are scanned to get metadata and it turned out some images dont have this metadata and it causes issues for some images.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same issue and it have been reported and fixed for 4.2.

I will get more information about when to expect release 4.2 or you can always grap it from codeplex and upgrade.

I will Update this post when I have more information about if there exist a quick fix.

Comment: estimate on 4.2 is a month.